# how to assign an id to every <p> with a specific bit of text inside?

Tags: javascript, html, innertext, ids

For example turning every `<p>thing to assign id to</p>` in the document into `<p id="something">thing to assign id to</p>`

this is my first question so pls point out anything I should include

I have not tried anything yet because I dont know how to do it.

Comment: please include the part of code for ```<p></p>``` tag, Every p tag you want to add id has same content ?

Comment: ids should be unique to each element, there should not be any two elements with the same id. Also this may be a case of [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you could describe what you're hoping this would accomplish it may be more helpful. Also I'd recommend checking out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: oh sorry i meant class lol

Comment: updated my answer @EL22310 to change classes not id.

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer your question, with the comment I made as a preface, you can grab all the p elements, filter for the ones with desired text, then change their ids using js.

I updated answer to add a class to the element instead of changing their id.

example:

```js
const targetText = "target text";
const allParagraphElements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
const pElementArray = Array.from(allParagraphElements);
const targetPs = pElementArray.filter(el => el.innerText == targetText);
targetPs.forEach(el => el.classList.add("target"));
```

```css
.target {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>I have text</p>
<p>I also have text</p>
<p>I also have text</p>
<p>target text</p>
<p>I also have text</p>
<p>target text</p>
```

Comment: you could also use the [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of filter, as ids should be unique and hopefully only one element matches your text. You could use a class instead for changing many elements. And instead of using a `==` comparison for target text, you could use [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using the loop counter itself...

```
var S='the text';

var P=document.getElementsByTagName('P');

for(var i=0; i<P.length; i++){

 if(P.innerHTML==S){P[i].id='P'+i;}


}
```

You'll end up with IDs that look like... P0, P1, P2, P3, etc